# Проблема с сравнением массивов в разных файлах

Tags: php

у меня есть 2 файла с раширением txt.
я обрабатываю файл №1 получается многомерный массив `print_r($columns)`:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] =>  1010111
        [1] => 56102999001
        [2] => 000
        [3] => 10101000000000916001
        [4] => ДА 
        [5] =>       4204920.71
        [6] =>       4204920.71
        [7] => КАССА                          
        [8] =>  
        [9] => 03.10.2011
        [10] =>      
        [11] => 202613789
        [12] =>      
        [13] =>        
        [14] => вал 
        [15] =>    
        [16] => 00 
    )
```

далее беру файл №2 и так же обрабатываю:
получается `print_r($stre)`:

```
Array 
(
[0] => 0001300002
[1] => 1
[2] => 1
[3] => 06
[4] => 
[5] => 000
[6] => 56102999001
[7] => 29803999001
[8] => 147862.00
[9] => 147862.00
[10] => 
[11] => 
[12] => 03.10.2011)
```

мне нужно сравнить  массив файла №1 и №2. в №1 нужно массив [1] сравнить с №2 массивы [6] и [7] и в вывести всю информацию со №2 файла где счёта совпадают! не важно либо [6] либо [7] с [1] с первого файла.

Comment: А где "проблема с сравнением массивов"? По тексту это не вопрос а постановка задачи.

Comment: как сравнить мне эти массивы и вывести инфу по счёту?

Answer (score 1):

С помощью `foreach($array as $key => $value)` пробегаемся по первому массиву и сравним значения с соответствующими ключами. Затем так же можно пробежаться по второму массиву, если нужна разница. Если нужен просто факт различия, достаточно знать, что при первой проверке различий нет и размеры массивов одинаковы.